# counting occurrences of numerical values in rows- Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Using DAX in PowerBI, I would like to count the number of times a list of values occurs in each row of my data set.
For example, if my raw data looks like this, and I want to find the number of occurrences of 17 OR 19...

|  | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 19 | 17 | 16 | 16 |
| Row 2 | 17 | 19 | 20 | 19 |

I'd like to create a measure that results in the following...

|  | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 2 |
| Row 2 | 3 |

Thanks! I'd appreciate the help! I will eventually need to do this for multiple different lists with different values of interest.

I have tried using some of the functions/online suggestions related to counting occurrences in columns, but I need to count occurrences by row. Unfortunately, I cannot transpose the data as I have too many rows; the transposed table results in an error saying PowerBI cannot support enough columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose/unpivot this in PowerQuery, and then it's super simple. In PowerQuery, select {"Row 1","Row 2"} column and then select Unpivot Other Columns. Then you'll end up with {RowNumber, Attribute, Value}

{Row1, A, 19},{Row 1, B, 17}...

and then you can just use  `CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Sheet1'),FILTER('Sheet1',OR([Value]=17,[Value]=19)))` in a matrix or table. ("Sheet1" is the name of my table...)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work on my actual data set. The real data set I need to sift through is much larger than the example I provided- I need to search through 50 columns with thousands of rows. I get an error when I attempt to transpose due to the large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform three step to execute this process .

1. First go to power query and include index column
2. Second Step is to Replace following Index Column with Row & IndexNum
3. Third Unpvitting all cell except Index Column . Followingw will help to convert all column into index with only Three Column Name "Index,Attribute,Value"
4. Next Step is to load the dataset into Model and use Formula in Dax by creating new calculated column.
5. Through DAX we can achieve the count
   CALCUATE(COUNTROW(TABLENAME) , ALLEXCEPT(TABLENAME,INDEX,ATTRIBUTE)

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Although you are asking for a DAX solution, I think the best one is you do it in the Power Query. Just add a new column with the below code-

```
List.Count( 
    List.Select(
        {[Column A], [Column B], [Column C], [Column D]},
        each _ = 19        
))+
List.Count( 
    List.Select(
        {[Column A], [Column B], [Column C], [Column D]},
        each _ = 17       
))
```

The output-

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without typing each individual column name? My actual data set has over 50 columns I need to search through. Thanks!

Comment: You can then duplicate your table and then Unpivot all other columns then first column. Then apply filter in the unpivoted column by 17 and 19. Now group by row column and count rows. Now you can join this new table to the older one.